# how can I change color of a NSToolBarItem?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to develop a editor, for that i want to set color of button according to selected color from the color panel.button is NSToolBarItem...How can I do it???

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSBarButtonItem and override the drawRect method based on the currently selected color.